# Can i play Google Documents files with Jw-Player?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, mediaelement.js

I want to play Google Doc. files with another player. (Mediaelement.js - JwPlayer..) because Google Doc. is using its own youtube player and I don't like it. Jw- player doesn't play these links.

Direct link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uSjTW2E4FGd1ozV3JIakE1NE0/edit?usp=sharing
embedLink: "https://video.google.com/get_player?ps=docs&partnerid=30&docid=0B1uSjTW2E4FGd1ozV3JIakE1NE0&BASE_URL=https://docs.google.com/"

How can I play on of them in Jw-Player, Mediaelements or an alternative player?

Comment: I'm afraid we don't support Google Documents files.

Comment: Hi Ethan. Thanks for your return.
I know, you don't support it but there is a way for play Google Doc. Because lots of users are playing Google Doc. files in JW-player and I want to know how. If you don't support, how these users can do it? I'm sure you have an idea.
Some users are using Mediaelemets player for Google Doc. files too. I think, they are using a plugin or something.
If you clarify this issue and show me a way, I will be very grateful.

With My Best Regards

Comment: There is not a way to play them.